# String tokenizer inexplicable behaviour

Tags: stringtokenizer

I have started this Text Summarization and Simplification project and I am using tokenizer to get the word count to calculate the readability of the text.

Here's the code snippet:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            wordcount++;
        }
        System.out.println(wordcount);
```

When I remove this line: System.out.println(st.nextToken()); the word count is not getting printed. The running doesn't stop. With the line the output as preferred is obtained.

Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`st.hasMoreTokens()` does not *take* an element off the Enumeration.  Therefore, `st.hasMoreTokens()` always returns `true`.  Thus, the `System.out.println()` method never gets called.

Comment: But then the same while statement should hold if I had used st.nextToken() too right? How did it it get printed in that case?

Comment: Actually, elements are _taken_ from the Enumeration when you call `st.nextToken()`.  This causes the `st.hasMoreTokens()` to eventually return `false` (when all elements have been _taken_ from the Enumeration), and you fall out of the `while()` loop.